# Custom setting Option for magento admin panel

Tags: module, custom-options, magento-2.2.5

I want make a custom option as custom module in admin panel in product adding or product edit option.

That there is custom checkbox will show by the name of "Check this box for showing this product only in home page".

How I can do it in Magento 2.2.5 version.
I'm little newbie in Magento 2.2.5 version.

Please help me how to do this as step by step.

Comment: You can proceed by creating product attribute (Like display on homepage). And then based on attribute show on homepage

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much @LAW for your help. I tried it and it works.
But if I want to make any type of extra custom option in admin panel, then what should I do?

Comment: I suggest that before proceeding further you should have a round of Magento admin panel. There are tons of things in admin which doesn't needs or needs little coding(If you have time).